# Special characters not being displayed correctly when being written to a csv file in excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to write strings containing special characters such as chinese letters and french accents to a csv file. At first I was getting the classic Unicode encode error and looked online for a solution. Many resources told me to use .encode('utf-8',errors='ignore') to solve the problem.This places bytes in the excel file. In my code shown below I tried getting the function that appends the character to the csv file to convert the character to utf-8. This makes the program run without error, however, when I open up the excel document I see that instead of "é" and "蒋" being added to the file, I see "Ã©" and "è’‹".

```
import csv

def appendToCSV(specialCharacter):
    with open('myCSVFile.csv',"a",newline="",encoding='utf-8') as csvFile:

        csvFileWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
        csvFileWriter.writerow([specialCharacter])

    csvFile.close()

appendToCSV('é')
appendToCSV('蒋')
```

I would like to get display the characters in the excel document exactly as shown, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `utf-8-sig` for the encoding.  Excel requires the byte order mark (BOM) signature or it will interpret the file in the local ANSI encoding.

Comment: This Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your *excel worksheet* is set to use "Latin 1". Try to [switch the setting](https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel) to use utf-8.

Note:

```
>>> x = "蒋"
>>> bs = x.encode()
>>> bs
b'\xe8\x92\x8b'
>>> bs.decode("latin")
'è\x92\x8b'
```

And:

```
>>> x = 'é'
>>> bs = x.encode()
>>> bs.decode('latin-1')
'Ã©'
```

Comment: I've changed the excel file to UTF-8, but nothing has changed. The characters are still being displayed incorrectly in the excel file. I tried copy and pasting the chinese letter into the excel file, but when I save it and open it again the chinese letter is replaced by a "?".

Comment: @WilliamO'Neill  How exactly did you try to change "the excel file"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I clicked "Save as" and under what type of file I want to save it as (CSV) there was a "UTF-8" option

Comment: @WilliamO'Neill That isn't the issue, although likely *that has messed up your file, because excel was interpreting it as latin, then you saved that interpretation as utf-8*. Rerun your code above, then open excel, not the file directly, and use `Data` -> `Get External Data` -> `Import Text File` and I believe it should prompt you to **open** (not save) the file using some encoding. Select utf-8. The issue is that excel is opening the file using the latin-1 codec, not that the *file itself* is encoded wrong. It is correctly encoded as utf-8.

Comment: I've opened an entirely new excel file and used the "Get Data from Text File / CSV" option, It simply loads the exact same characters found in the excel file that the python code writes the data to. Also, once it is fixed, will every excel file I open be able to handle chinese characters, or will I have to repeat this for every new file I create that must include special characters such as these?

Comment: @WilliamO'Neill I'm sorry, but I don't understand if you were able to open your csv in excel with the right encoding or not. As to whether or not you will have to do this every time, I can't really say because I don't use Excel (or any Microsoft Office products really). But keep in mind, there is no such thing to the computer as "chinese characters" or any characters at all. The computer only sees bytes. Chinese characters can be represented by different encodings, (the so-called Big5, unicode, etc..).

Comment: I apologize for the confusion and am very thankful for your help. I was able to open the csv in excel, but the encoding was not correct. Non ACII characters are still either being written to the excel file incorrectly, or being encoded by the excel file incorrectly.

Comment: @WilliamO'Neill did you see an option for selecting an encoding to use *when opening*? Have you tried the solutions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel)? Assuming you are on Python 3, your code correctly writes utf-8 encoded bytes to the file.